# How to open app screen on particular push notification when phone is in lock mode

Tags: android, notifications, push

I want to launch an activity when getting particular ( i check notification body content ) notification, My code is working when my app is in the foreground, background and killed state. But Not Worked when my phone is locked. getting notification body content blank in a toast when the phone is locked but notification is seen.

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
          public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
           Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    // Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
           Log.d(TAG, "FCM Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());

    str = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

         StringBuilder myNumbers = new StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
          if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
           myNumbers.append(str.charAt(i));
           System.out.println(str.charAt(i) + " is a digit.");
       } else {
           System.out.println(str.charAt(i) + " not a digit.");
       }
       }
        System.out.println("Your numbers: " + myNumbers.toString());

    str.replaceAll("\\D+", "");`enter code here`
    String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
    FirstWord1 = splited[0];
    String FirstWord = splited[1];

    System.out.println("FW Word : " + FirstWord);
    System.out.println("0 Word : " + FirstWord1);

    //String FirstWord = splited[0];
    ticketNo = myNumbers.toString();
    GlobalVeriable.msg = FirstWord;
    GlobalVeriable.ticketNo = ticketNo;
    GlobalVeriable.showPopupStr = str;
    GlobalVeriable.showPopupFirstword = FirstWord1;
    GlobalVeriable.showMyNo = myNumbers.toString();

    if (FirstWord1.equals("Please")) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverlayActivity.class);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
     } 
    else {

      Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,   PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
         Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         String channelId = "Default";
         NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,          channelId)
                 .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                 .setSound(sound)
                 //  .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                 // .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                 .setAutoCancel(true)
                 .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
         ;
         NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)        getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
             NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default      channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
             manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

         }
         manager.notify(0, builder.build());
 }

@Override
 public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();

         Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverlayActivity.class);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         intent.putExtra("firstWord", FirstWord1);
         startActivity(intent);
}


}


OverlayActivity.java


public class OverlayActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = OverlayActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[onCreate]");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentType.OVERLAY.getTag());


        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = OverlayFragment.newInstance();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, FragmentType.OVERLAY.getTag());
        ft.commit();
    }

    private enum FragmentType {
        OVERLAY("overlay");
        private String tag;

        private FragmentType(String tag) {
            this.tag = tag;
        }

        public String getTag() {
            return tag;
        }
    }
}


OverlayFragment.java


public class OverlayFragment extends Fragment {

    MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
    public static OverlayFragment newInstance() {
        OverlayFragment fragment = new OverlayFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overlay, container, false);

        Button close = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.close);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
       // GlobalVeriable.showPopupFirstword="Please";
    //    GlobalVeriable.showPopupFirstword= getArguments().getString("firstWord");


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),GlobalVeriable.showPopupFirstword,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"msg"+GlobalVeriable.msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (GlobalVeriable.showPopupFirstword.equals("Please") /*|| GlobalVeriable.showPopupFirstword.equals("")*/){

            //

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),R.raw.ring);
            mp.start();
            final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder=new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(" Vistor Request ");
            builder.setMessage(GlobalVeriable.showPopupStr);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
      builder.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    mp.stop();
                    GlobalVeriable.notiMsg="In";
                    //sendOwnerResponce();


                }
            });//builder.show();
            builder.setNegativeButton("Reject", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    mp.stop();
                    GlobalVeriable.notiMsg="Out";
                    //sendOwnerResponce();
                }
            });

            // Dialog
            final android.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#48A21D"));
            dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.RED);

            new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //dialog.setMessage("00:"+ (millisUntilFinished/1000));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
//info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    mp.stop();
                    getActivity().finish();

                    //callStatus(AppSharedPreference.getID(),mobile,flat);
                }
            }.start();


            //mp.stop();
        }
        else {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt FirebaseMessagingService works like that, i would suggest writing your own service and make it work in foreground and handle your code there.